# Updated Typo3 news extension, now "News Administration" displays an error ...LinkButton" is not valid

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I have recently updated the news extension for my Typo3 installation. Now, if I click on the button "News Administration" on the left panel and then on the folder with my news, I get an error:

*Button "TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Template\Components\Buttons\LinkButton" is not valid*
The provided link shows it's the TYPO3 exception 1441706370.

I am running an old Typo3 version (7.6.19.) which I wanted to update. But I thought it'd be wise to first update all extensions before updating Typo3 (and PHP and MySQL..).

- PHP 7.4.33
- MySQL 5.7.38

What is now the smartest way to go on? I want to ensure that my system will run later with the newest versions without any data loss on the way.

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1441706370.html) and the changelog of the news extension. But I did not find a hint on what to do yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you planned to upgrade to the latest version greater than 7.x then you better ignore this. just focus on upgrade wizards that you don't miss any upgrade wizard provided by some extensions to upgrade from one version of TYPO3  to another version.

Comment: I second that! TYPO3 brings upgrade wizards always for two versions, so you can update TYPO3 7.6 to 9.5 and then to 11.5. In regards of the news extension you go to EXT:news version 8.6 first and then with TYPO3 11.5 to EXT:news 10.0.3.